# How can I use pandas agg to sum booleans and always obtain numbers as result?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with a bool type column. I would like to obtain the number of True values per id using pandas' groupby and agg functions. I've done this a bunch of times, but it seems the resulting column's type depends on the data frame. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd    
d = {'id': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'bool': [True, False, False, True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df.groupby(['id']).agg({'bool': 'sum'}))
```

The output I get from this code is:

```
   id   bool
0   1   True
1   2  False
2   3   True
```

Which is not what I want. Now, if agg tries to sum two True values:

```
import pandas as pd    
d = {'id': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'bool': [True, True, False, True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df.groupby(['id']).agg({'bool': 'sum'}))
```

Then I get:

```
   id                 bool
0   1                 2.00
1   2                 0.00
2   3                 1.00
```

Which is how I want.

I've seen situations in which a few rows are of type bool, whereas others are type float. It seems to be related with the number of rows grouped: if only one row, then it shows the bool value; if more than one, resulting type is float. I would like the resulting aggregated columns to always be of type float.

Pandas version is 1.0.1

Comment: convert your boolean column to `int`: `df['bool'] = df['bool'].astype(int)`

Answer (score 3):

You can sum and keep the output as a float in all cases with the following:

```
import pandas as pd    
d = {'id': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'bool': [True, False, False, True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df.groupby(['id'])['bool'].sum().astype(float))
```

Yields the output

```
id
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
Name: bool, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the max function

```
df.groupby(['id']).agg({'bool': 'max'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [typecast to float](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html). Use reset_index if you want a separate column for your index at the end

```
df.groupby(['id']).agg({'bool': 'sum'}).astype(float).reset_index()
```

Example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd    
>>> d = {'id': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'bool': [True, True, False, True]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> 
>>> df.groupby(['id']).agg({'bool': 'sum'}).astype(float).reset_index()
   id  bool
0   1   2.0
1   2   0.0
2   3   1.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated *Numpy* function to count non-zero cells
(*True* is counted as *1*, *False* as *0*). So you can run:

```
df.groupby(['id']).bool.agg(lambda gr: np.count_nonzero(gr))
```

I assume that you want **integer** number of *True* values.
Otherwise append `.astype(float)`.